# Read large decimal values from excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have to extract data from the excel files which contains large decimal values.
I have tried reading it through xlrd and pandas both but the same error in both cases.

```
from xlrd import *
import decimal
workbook =open_workbook('C:\Users\KRISHNA\Desktop\ERIAN\Data\TARGET-AREA.xlsx')
```

> Error
>
> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position
>   2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

At this beginning stage only I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the string prefix "C:\Users". \U is interpreted as a unicode sequence beginning. Prefix your string with "r" to indicate that it is a raw string:

```
from xlrd import * 
import decimal 
workbook = open_workbook(r'C:\Users\KRISHNA\Desktop\ERIAN\Data\TARGET-AREA.xlsx')
```